# Visual Studio. Get all called function

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, macros, vs-extensibility

Is there a way to get all function used in code.
Actualy I have a big dll which provides me an api of third-party system and now I need list of functions from this dll  I'm using.

Is it possible? What way is better: macro or vs extension?

Comment: What language? The Roslyn compiler in C# for example exposes all this information.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos C#

Comment: Wouldn't a simple .NET decompiler do the trick? Or do you wan't to know exactly which methods are called from your code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the API has a separate namespace. Unless you use explicit calls like: Third.party.namespace.ClassName.Method() you can remove using clauses and then filter somehow the errors the compiler shows you while rebuilding.
Or you can start by removing the references to the 3rd party assemblies, which will generate errors for all usings. Then you remove the using and then see every bit of code that relies on them. As I said unless there are explicit calls (which means there were some ambiguities) this should work.